# Arduino + NRF24L01 mesh network implementation

Tags: nrf24l01+, wireless, networking

TL;DR

- I want to produce a large self configuring wireless mesh network using Arduinos and NRF24L01s transceivers. These have been chosen because they are capable of achieving the requirement and the application is cost sensitive.
- I cannot find any "plug it in and run" system , although the RF24Mesh, RF24, RF24Network libraries produced by  TMRh20 / Avamander have the capabilities to produce such a system.
- Information on suitable software is sought.

---

I'm using Arduino / C++ on a project that requires mesh radio connection of, ideally hundreds of sensors*. If required the network can be partitioned to overcome addressing or traffic capacity issues, but this will probably not be necessary.

I am using NRF24L01 transceivers due to acceptable performance, energy use, range** and cost issues. There will also be one or more cellphone-network gateways per mesh network. I am also investigating the use of LORA in some situations.

I can currently achieve NRF24L01 + Arduino capability over a few nodes.
I could extend this to a semi-indefinite number of nodes but not in a sensible manner

**Requirement:**

- I wish to implement a "many node" wireless mesh network* with automatic inclusion of new nodes, and the ability mainly to transfer data from nodes to a master, but with some master to node traffic. Average data rate per node can be as low as is required to ensure operation with whatever number of nodes happen to be connected. (Nodes do not 'move about' physically, but new nodes may be added and others may occasionally be disabled.)

I am capable, needs must, of wading through what is available and 'learning the hard way' but hope that a reasonably complete solution is available. I have a large amount of experience in software development on microprocessors / microcontrollers over about 45 years, but much of this is 'bare metal' in assembler.
I was hoping that something close to 'it just works' may be available.

I have spent "many hours" internet searching to find what is available, and have been surprised at the extremely small number of sites reporting availability of anything close to this specification. The libraries implemented by TMRh20 / Avamander (RF24Mesh, RF24, RF24Network) as commented on in his blog [here](https://tmrh20.blogspot.com/2019/05/rf24mesh-dynamic-mesh-networking-for.html?m=1) seem fully capable of this task but still seem to require me to know rather more than I do - so far :-)
I have not found any posts in this group that address the requirement.
Any sites that I have found propose multiple node networks are useful for small tasks but limited in extensibility and lack mesh addressing automation features.

- Example only. This site offers [Arduino Wireless Network with Multiple NRF24L01 Modules](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-to-build-an-arduino-wireless-network-with-multiple-nrf24l01-modules/) but requires a very 'manual' network construction process.
- This probably comes closest of what I found  - [Cheap Arduino mesh using RF24 radio modules](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2016/05/30/cheap-arduino-mesh-using-rf24-radio-modules/). It utilises RF24, RF24Network and RF24Mesh libraries but is also relatively incomplete.

**Any advice on how to achieve my aim would be welcome.**

---

*The application is the management of solar lighting, and usage and availability / status reporting for women's toilets in refugee camps. The ability to remotely reconfigure energy use profiles in low sun periods may be useful. Additional features such as alarm provision may be considered.

Information can include lighting operation statistics and current state, energy use and battery state, toilet usage and availability, ... .

**I am aware that some "clone" versions have range issues.

---

Note:  The NRF24L01 was chosen due to a combination of cost and low current when continuously receiving. The latter removes the need for time-crucial synchronisation and greatly simplifies multi hop mesh implementation. Energy budget is extremely limited and a far easier eg ESP8266 based solution is, at least so far, untenable.